# crypto.createHmac is undefined after rollup

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I'm trying to `rollup` my library's code into a `dist` folder.
Right now I have a problem with the built in `crypto` library.

terminal output:

```
$ yarn run build
  ...
  lib/helpers/security.js
  createHmac is not exported by node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/empty.js
  ...
```

### Rollup config

```
...
plugins: [
  builtins(),
  resolve(),
  json(),
  babel({
    exclude: ['node_modules/**','**/*.json']
  })
]
...
```

### Source code

A snippet from my source code:

```
// lib/helpers/security.js
import * as crypto from 'crypto'
crypto.createHmac('sha256',nonce).update(text).digest('base64');
```

### Result

From the *rolled-up*, bundled `js` output:

```
undefined('sha256', nonce).update(text).digest('base64');
```

### Crypto.js source code

For reference the relevant `export` statement in `node/crypto.js` on github shows that createHmac is being exported.

[node/crypto.js L147](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f86a181d471099417828ffd787aa6b3e0356ac36/lib/crypto.js#L147)

### Update 1 ( Solution? )

It seems that removing the `import` line from `security.js` resolves the issue. I understand that `crypto` is a built in node module.

I want to understand *why* I should not `import` in this case while examples in the documentation do *import* the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is the solution I came up with which works fine for me.

Install [`rollup-plugin-node-builtins`](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/rollup-plugin-node-builtins) in your project as a dev dependency. And import it in your `rollup.config.js`:

```
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins'
```

Set `crypto` to `false` when using `builtins()`. It defaults to the `commonjs` version from `browserify`. That's not I wanted or needed.

```
// set crypto: false when using builtins()
...
builtins({crypto: false}),
...
```

Make sure to add `crypto` to your [`external`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#peer-dependencies) option:

```
// add `crypto` to the `external` option
// you probably already have 
// one or more libs defined in there
let external = ['crypto']
```

Now I can use `crypto` in my library without the previous problems when using my built files.

```
import { createHmac } from "crypto";
```

The result is a module, 4KB in size, which depends on several external dependencies, without having them included in the built files.

For context: my source code is written in ES6 and I am building three versions of my module: `cjs`, `umd` and `es`.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid to babel server-side files, it can be done, but I prefer not doing it.
So you will probably not have the errors if you use require() instead of import (import is not built-in in Node.js v8):

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
```